# How to define a plugin in gradle version catalog

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

How to define a plugin in gradle version catalog that it can be used in the gradle.build file?
I have only found an example for toml file but not for groovy.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            //            plugin('org.springframework.boot:2.7.8')??
            //            plugin('io.spring.dependency-management:1.1.0')??
            
            library('groovy-core', 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.5')
            library('groovy-json', 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.5')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to update gradle to version 7.6 and then it worked like this

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create('libs') {
            plugin('spring-boot', 'org.springframework.boot').version('2.7.8')
            plugin('spring-dependency-management', 'io.spring.dependency-management').version('1.1.0')
...
```